# How to calculate a file size from URL in java

Tags: java

I'm attempting to get a bunch of pdf links from a web service and I want to give the user the file size of each link.

Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Thanks

Comment: I afraid you will have to download the file at least once to get exact size. (you may want to store for future, but if files changes on the server the data will be stale)

Comment: @Nishant That's not true. An `HTTP HEAD` request returns information about what you would get if you did an `HTTP GET` request, which should include size of the returned request. You could certainly do a `HEAD` request and parse the response.

Comment: but the `content-length` is optional and may not be present

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Using a HEAD request, you can do something like this:

```
private static int getFileSize(URL url) {
    URLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = url.openConnection();
        if(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
            ((HttpURLConnection)conn).setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        }
        conn.getInputStream();
        return conn.getContentLength();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
            ((HttpURLConnection)conn).disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the below exception: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL. I am ablo to open the pdf link in browser. Does it mean this url wont allow head request?

Comment: Can you share your request URL?

Comment: I am sorry... Url needs my credentials. I cannot share it. :(

Comment: @ravi if 405, use "GET" instead of "HEAD".

Comment: It returned -1. when i run in debug mode and look into conn object i am seeing many fields as null or false or -1

Comment: This throws an NPE at `conn.disconnect()` if the URL can't be opened

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer is prone to `NullPointerException`, doesn't work for files > 2GiB and contains an unnecessary call to `getInputStream()`. Here's the fixed code:

```
public long getFileSize(URL url) {
  HttpURLConnection conn = null;
  try {
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    return conn.getContentLengthLong();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } finally {
    if (conn != null) {
      conn.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:** The accepted was updated but still has issues.

Answer (score 10):

Try to use HTTP HEAD method. It returns the HTTP headers only. The header `Content-Length` should contain information you need.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try already to use [getContentLength](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) on the URL connection?
In case the server responses a valid header you should get the size of the document.

But be aware of the fact that the webserver might also return the file in chunks. In this case IIRC the content length method will return either the size of one chunk (<=1.4) or -1 (>1.4).

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP response has a Content-Length header, so you could query the URLConnection object for this value.

Once the URL connection has been opened, you can try something like this:

```
List values = urlConnection.getHeaderFields().get("content-Length")
if (values != null && !values.isEmpty()) {

    // getHeaderFields() returns a Map with key=(String) header 
    // name, value = List of String values for that header field. 
    // just use the first value here.
    String sLength = (String) values.get(0);

    if (sLength != null) {
       //parse the length into an integer...
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are on Android, here's a solution in Java:

```
/**@return the file size of the given file url , or -1L if there was any kind of error while doing so*/
@WorkerThread
public static long getUrlFileLength(String url) {
    try {
        final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        final String lengthHeaderField = urlConnection.getHeaderField("content-length");
        Long result = lengthHeaderField == null ? null : Long.parseLong(lengthHeaderField);
        return result == null || result < 0L ? -1L : result;
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    return -1L;
}
```

And in Kotlin:

```
/**@return the file size of the given file url , or -1L if there was any kind of error while doing so*/
@WorkerThread
fun getUrlFileLength(url: String): Long {
    return try {
        val urlConnection = URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        urlConnection.requestMethod = "HEAD"
        urlConnection.getHeaderField("content-length")?.toLongOrNull()?.coerceAtLeast(-1L)
                ?: -1L
    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        -1L
    }
}
```

If your app is from Android N, you can use this instead:

```
/**@return the file size of the given file url , or -1L if there was any kind of error while doing so*/
@WorkerThread
fun getUrlFileLength(url: String): Long {
    return try {
        val urlConnection = URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        urlConnection.requestMethod = "HEAD"
        urlConnection.contentLengthLong.coerceAtLeast(-1L)
    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        -1L
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried all the possible ways but it always returns -1. Also bellow attached is the header data:

Comment: {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Accept-Ranges=[bytes], Cache-Control=[max-age=2592000], Connection=[keep-alive, Keep-Alive], Content-Type=[application/vnd.android.package-archive], Date=[Thu, 25 Jul 2019 14:01:44 GMT], ETag=["3f416f-58e6adf532900-gzip"], Expires=[Sat, 24 Aug 2019 14:01:44 GMT], Keep-Alive=[timeout=3, max=75], Last-Modified=[Wed, 24 Jul 2019 10:35:48 GMT], Server=[Apache/2.4.39 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2r mod_bwlimited/1.4 Phusion_Passenger/5.3.7], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked],

Comment: Upgrade=[h2,h2c], Vary=[Accept-Encoding,User-Agent], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1564063303579], X-Android-Response-Source=[NETWORK 200], X-Android-Selected-Protocol=[http/1.1], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1564063302765]}

Comment: @golchha21 What is this?

Comment: This is the data that is returned when I used urlConnection.headerFields

Comment: @golchha21 Well, if the server doesn't return it to you, it means the function I've made should return -1 as a fallback, because the size is unknown.

Comment: That I understand but when I checked the header data with another tool via a browser the Content-Length was visible there.

Comment: I suggest to create a new question here. It might be related to the server itself. What is the server and what is the tool you've used? Write it down on the new question thread

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
private long getContentLength(HttpURLConnection conn) {
    String transferEncoding = conn.getHeaderField("Transfer-Encoding");
    if (transferEncoding == null || transferEncoding.equalsIgnoreCase("chunked")) {
        return conn.getHeaderFieldInt("Content-Length", -1);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
```