# How to find out efficiently total size of a file to be downloaded without using Content-Length

Tags: java, http, http-headers, download, server

I know it can be done using `content-length` field of response header. But what happens when the response header does not contain the `content-length` field? I tried binary searching over which maximum byte is present in the file. I used this method for the binary searching to check if the file to be downloaded contains a `byteNo` byte-

```
private boolean fileContainsByte(long byteNo) {
    try {
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + byteNo + "-");
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        int v = inputStream.read();

        if (v == -1)
            return false;

        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But binary searching to determine file length turns out to be extremely slow. Moreover for some download files this method doesn't work(Probably for the servers that doesn't support `range` header field for download files).

I have googled it a lot and didn't find a solution to this problem. I've noticed that for example for this [Book](http://www.cluster2.hostgator.co.in/files/writeable/uploads/hostgator99706/file/letusc-yashwantkanetkar.pdf). I can't even determine the file size with my code(try `content-length` method, if it fails do the binary search). But when I try downloading it with wGet or IDM, they total file size is displayed within 2 seconds after creating the download. How do they do it?

Comment: If you want to know the size of a stream, you need to read the whole stream.

Comment: In that case how are wGet and IDM doing it so fast? Are they determining the file size on their server?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800588/how-to-calculate-a-file-size-from-url-in-java

Comment: Do you get the Content-Length with a HEAD request? You could always look at the [`wget` source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/).

Comment: When I make a HEAD request (`curl -I`) to that book, it has `Content-Length: 7580198`

Comment: This is most likely due to the fact that the server is responding with [Transfer-Encoding: chunked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). These types of responses do not include a Content-Length header because they include the size of the chunks in the payload as a sort of preamble to each chunk's data. I don't know enough Java to be able to answer the question, but I believe your answer lies with a better understanding of chunked transfers.