# How to get video download size from URL for dailymotion

Tags: java, android

I am developing a video downloader and want to display the size of downloadable file to the user. How can I achieve this?

I have tried the following chunk of code, but it is returning the size of the link rather than the actual size of video.

```
URLConnection fbCon;
            fbCon = new URL(link).openConnection();
fbCon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
            size = String.valueOf(fbCon.getContentLength()) ;
```

I have used code from the following link:
https://github.com/hikikomoriphoenix/Beedio

VideoContentSarch.java file contains the code to get the size of video currently playing.

I want to get the actual size of the video currently playing, but I am getting the size of the link for the videos being played on Vimeo and Dailymotion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate a file size from URL in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800588/how-to-calculate-a-file-size-from-url-in-java)

Comment: For the link of Dailymotion and Vimeo it is returning 0.